# Problem with my wifi netwowrk

Tags: wifi

my name is Francesco, i send you one question for the problem with my wifi. I Install today this OS but my Wifi don't start. My network wifi is REALTEK 8821CE and my os don't find them. If you have a solution please help me. Bye

Comment: try [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/379049/realtek-wifi-driver-problem-in-linux-mint-18-2/400259#400259)

Answer (score 1):

I have the same network card, lenovo ideapad 330-15arr.

This work, tested

https://askubuntu.com/questions/990378/wi-fi-not-working-on-lenovo-thinkpad-e570-realtek-rtl8821ce

Only problem is you do not have make and the necessary dependencies out of the bat so first you need to connect to the internet by other means

I used my phone's USB tethering then:

- `sudo apt update`
- `sudo apt upgrade`
- `sudo install make`

, and after that you do inside `8821ce` folder:

- `make all`
- `make install`
- `modprobe -a 8821ce`