# Juno - HP PAVILION 15 - No WiFi after installation

Tags: release-juno, wifi, drivers, laptop

I did a fresh install in a laptop, and I have no WiFi. I don't have the option neither.

- I ran the command `lspci` and I saw my network controllers is RTL8821CE.
- I also ran `sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source` and rebooted the machine, but still no WiFi.

The laptop doesn't have an Ethernet port so WiFi is the only option to connect to a Network. Right now I'm using my phone to connect to Internet via USB as a temporary solution.

The laptop brand and model is: HP PAVILION 15-CW0053LA

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check the updates tab of  Appcenter. It should show a WiFi driver there. If you install it you won't need to follow the steps in the answers

Answer (score 2):

As defined earlier but never approved as answer here so I can't mark it as duplicate

This clearly should be the answer for that WiFi module

---

From:

https://askubuntu.com/a/990571/890782

### Getting the Driver

- Download the driver from [here](https://github.com/endlessm/linux/tree/master/drivers/net/wireless/rtl8821ce) by using the link below

  - https://minhaskamal.github.io/DownGit/#/home?url=https://github.com/endlessm/linux/tree/master/drivers/net/wireless/rtl8821ce
- Open a terminal window and enter to the directory you downloaded the file, for example could be `$HOME/Downloads`
- Enter the directory

  - `$ cd ~/Downloads`
- Unzip the file, if you don't have the `unzip` command just run `sudo apt install unzip` and run the command again

  - `$ unzip rtl8821ce.zip`
- Enter the newly created directory

  - `$ cd rtl8821ce`

### Preparation

- Edit the file `Makefile` using any editor you want, here I'll be using nano ([nano Basics](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Nano/Basics_Guide))

  - `$ nano Makefile`
- Now scroll down (around line 150) to a line that reads

  ```
  export TopDIR ?= $(srctree)/drivers/net/wireless/rtl8821ce
  ```
- And change it to

  ```
  export TopDIR ?= $ ~/Downloads/rtl8821ce
  ```

> *If you downloaded the file elsewhere in the start of the process just change `~/Downloads` to the proper directory you are working on*

- Save the file (in nano <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> and then <kbd>ENTER</kbd>) and close the editor (in nano <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>)

Now we need to install some essentials to build in the system

- Run

  - `sudo apt install build-essential`
- After it we start to build the module we require

### To Build and Install the Module

Run the following commands:

- `$ make`

> Creates the module in the working dir

- `$ sudo make install`

> Installs the module in the system

- `$ sudo modprobe 8821ce`

> Loads the module in the system

---

Now you probably have a functioning WiFi driver and WiFi connection

Do Not delete the files of the driver you downloaded. You'll need them in the future.

---

As a future remainder, you'll have to do this every time you update the kernel (`linux-image`) in your system. Maybe in the future the kernel will give you a functioning driver out of the box, but in case it won't just redo the steps but first you have to clean the directory you were working by using the command

- `$ cd ~/Downloads/rtl8821ce`
- `$ make clean`

Then, as I said redo the commands to build the module for the new kernel

```
$ make
$ sudo make install
$ sudo modprobe 8821ce
```

ref:

https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/17308/14940

https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/17711/14940

https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=90&t=273099&p=1501349#p1501349

Comment: Thx very much! =), this solved the problem, i was getting an error in the make step, fixed using this https://github.com/tomaspinho/rtl8821ce

Answer (score 1):

I posted this in another thread and it may be of help.

Before anything, before any input or *sudo* code in Terminal, I believe it is worth checking in the Apps window, start typing **Software** and it will show something like **Software & Updates**. It is on the upper-left corner.

For me, in the 5th tab, it shows ***Additional Drivers*** and from there I could select an **unknown device** to *use dkms source for the r8812au network driver*. (mine is 8812au, but well, choose whichever you need).

Hope this helps from a clean install and without internet. If you can, just connect it with a cable or another USB adapter and spare yourself the hassle by doing this.

Answer (score 0):

for me ( hp pc ) work this [enter link description here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H-xb9kBl2P0)

```
sudo modprobe -r rtl8723be

sudo modprobe rtl8723be ant_sel=2

echo "options rtl8723be ant_sel=2" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723-ant-sel.confecho
```