# How to Install Driver for Realtek RTL8822BE in Juno

Tags: wifi, release-juno, laptop

I'm a total newb to Linux, and I'm not that computer savvy in the first place. Please forgive me if this question is merely an advertisement for my ignorance.

I managed to get eOS **Juno** installed on my **HP Stream 11**, but no wifi. I read in other threads that it's possible Juno's wifi drivers are, uhm, sub-optimal?

I was able to figure out that the laptop has a **Realtek** `RTL8822BE` chipset. It worked fine in the Windows that came installed on the laptop. The Stream's drive isn't big enough for a parallel installation -- I've got to wipe the drive for a Linux installation so recovering from the first installation was pretty time consuming. (Actually I have a related question to that issue - asked separately). I'd like to avoid going through that again.

1. From where should I obtain the Linux driver for this chipset? Is
   there a preferred source?
2. Once I've found it, I download it to a USB drive?
3. Then, do the Juno install and run something from the terminal to install the driver?

Thanks in advance for your patience.

Answer (score 1):

1. In Linux the majority of drivers come with the Kernel
2. No because it exists in your system, the problem might be another thing
3. No, again, In Linux usually you install the system and is working out of the box because comes with drivers (modules), only if you need them there are some proprietary drivers available to install like Graphics drivers but even for them you have the open source counterpart already and you choose to install the other one to get more performance (sometimes, depending of your hardware)

If you check inside `/lib/firmware/rtlwifi/`

```
ls /lib/firmware/rtlwifi/
```

, you'll find `rtl8822befw.bin` which is your module so you already have it if you installed `juno`

---

Now about your problem, it might need more research I'll update this post if I found something to help you, but first I wanted to clarify some concepts for you to know

And in case it might help you, elementaryOS `Juno` is based on Ubuntu 18.04 `Bionic`. So if you want to find answers elsewhere, some directed to that distro and version might help you aswell

---

**UPDATE**

You could try this

https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/17764/14940

Comment: If this driver is already included with the OS, why isn't it installed automatically? Windows has made this easy since 1998. Does one really have to make and compile their own WiFi drivers on modern Linux operating systems? This makes me sad.