# HP 15-da0103ng WIFI not working

Tags: wifi, release-juno, drivers, laptop

I just bought an HP 15-da0103ng. Unfortunately WIFI is not working with elementary OS 5. I tried several approaches to install a Driver for Realtek 8821CE but so far nothing turned out to work. Can somebody help please?

I am more or less not familiar with Terminal operations so please post step by step guide.

Many Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

You should try a possible solution I wrote in detail based on https://askubuntu.com/a/990571/890782

---

Check it out here:

https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/17764/14940

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a recent and common issue on askubuntu after a bit of googling. Have you tried [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1074179/the-wifi-adapter-chipset-realtek-8821ce-is-not-found-after-upgraded-to-ubuntu) yet? Unfortunately it seems it's a manual fix for now.