# Driver Realtek RTL8821CE

Tags: release-juno, touchpad, drivers

Hola que tal acabo de instalar Elementary OS Juno y no me reconoce la tarjeta inalámbrica de mi computadora, es una HP Probook 440 G5.
Y como puedo configurar el Touchpad, no me da la funcion de Clic Derecho?
Espero su amable asistencia, Saludos!

**English translation:** 
Hello, I just installed Elementary OS Juno and it does not recognize my computer's wireless card, it's an HP Probook 440 G5. Also how can I configure the Touchpad?, because the Right Click function doesn't work. Thanks in advance, Regards

Comment: **ES: ** Este sitio es en inglés no español. Posiblemente existe alguien que entienda español y te pueda ayudar como yo. Pero trata de ahora en adelante a escribir en inglés. Iba a escribir tu pregunta en inglés pero alguien ya la editó y está pendiente de aprobación **| EN: ** This website is in English not Spanish. Maybe there's someone who could help you and understands Spanish like me. But from now on try to write in English. I was about to translate the question into English but someone already edited the question and now is pending approval

Answer (score 0):

I have a notebook with a Realtek's wireless card. It's awful! I google this driver and find it.

https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=90&t=273099&p=1501349#p1501349

Maybe it helps. ;)