# Wifi still dont work after a new fresh install

Tags: wifi, networking, internet

Well I'm realy new in Linux and I install Elementary os juno but. I have a problem i cant use wifi in win 10 it was no problem but I realy want to use my notebook with wifi and not with an Lan cable. I'm now Search for days an a solution but all other dont help me. What can I do ??

and sorry for double posting the same question again the first time I post it as a guest and can't comment to people :( And if is not realy clear I have definitely a problem with elementary and not with windows, because I delete the hole ssd to Install elemantary.

Sorry for my realy bad english

Comment: Please go to AppCenter([tag:appcenter]) over an Ethernet connection and click on the installed tab. If you see **bcmwl-kernel-source**, install it by clicking on free. Your WiFi([tag:wifi]) should be working again.

Comment: I don‘t have a bcmwl-kernel-source in the appcenter. And I have a new Problem I Lose sometimes the Internet Connection Even when I Connect with the Ethernet.

Comment: Sorry for the late-reply, i don't know how i ignored this. Please take a look here, https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/16760/problem-with-my-wifi-netwowrk